# Knockout JS - CSS Binding with dash in class name

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a data binding in Knockout to apply a CSS class if a condition is true. When I use a dash in the class name (such as test-class) then I get a javascript error.

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/sgvem/2/

```
<p data-bind="text: property, css: { with-dash: property().length > 0 }"></p>
```

Is there a way to add a class with a dash using Knockout JS?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Just put it in quotes:

```
<p data-bind="text: property, css: { 'with-dash': property().length > 0 }"></p>
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgvem/3/).

As a side note, you don't need the `> 0` since a `length` of `0` will evaluate to `false`, and any other length will evaluate to `true`:

```
<p data-bind="text: property, css: { 'with-dash': property().length }"></p>
```

Comment: Had to mark yours as the answer for adding the nice tidbit about length :)

Answer (score 7):

You can qualify the name using '

Like this:

```
<p data-bind="text: property, css: { 'with-dash': property().length > 0 }"></p>
```

Your Fiddle, [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/sgvem/4/)

Here are the Knockout docs explaining the css binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html