# How to add data dash attribute using knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I need attribute like data-id, data-action

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable3">
        <ol class="dd-list">
            <li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="13">
                <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div><div class="dd3-content">Item 13</div>
            </li>
            <li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="14">
                <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div><div class="dd3-content">Item 14</div>
            </li>
            <li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="15">
                <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div><div class="dd3-content">Item 15</div>
                <ol class="dd-list">
                    <li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="16">
                        <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div><div class="dd3-content">Item 16</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="17">
                        <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div><div class="dd3-content">Item 17</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="18">
                        <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div><div class="dd3-content">Item 18</div>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
```

I need to create the attribute data-id="13".
How do I create it with knockout js attr binding...

Comment: What do you have so far? Have you read the [attr binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) it has a section about the data dash attributes at the end...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with knockoutjs attr to write data\* attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471018/working-with-knockoutjs-attr-to-write-data-attributes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Knockout JS - CSS Binding with dash in class name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283328/knockout-js-css-binding-with-dash-in-class-name)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the attr binding `data-bind="attr: {'data-id': id}"`